# Ionic + AngularJs + Token based authentication

Tags: angularjs, cordova, authentication, ionic-framework

I've set up a standard Ionic Framework (with `ionic start myapp tabs`), and I've got a Laravel PHP backend on the other side (which has the database and so on).

Now what I want is to ask the database of my backend from my mobile-app (it'll be a native app, compiled by PhoneGap). There's problems with CORS to be solved, it seems, and I've read a lot of approaches on how to do it, but none really worked.

What is a good way to authenticate (token-based) to my external backend server, and then, once authenticated ask the server API for various things? Does anyone additionally have a good tutorial and/or working example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719894/login-with-ionic-and-material-design/29934933#29934933 look at my answer here. May help you.

Answer (score 2):

This is the tutorial may help you how to use token system with angular and node js.Coming to data base you can use mysql.When using token based authentication header should have a valid token on every end point to server.you can your feasible token generators also lik oauth2.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543

Answer (score 1):

To solve CORS problem add this php code to the head of your php api

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 166400'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this response can do something good right now. But to be precise, CORS can be avoid by following below steps.

First create a separate php file in your server and named it as "api.php" (or whatever you prefer) and include this.

```
   <?php
       if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
           header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
           header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
           header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
       }

       // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
       if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

           if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
                header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

           if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
                header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

           exit(0);
       }
   ?>
```

Then in you other php files which send responses to the client use

```
   include_once './api.php'; // or the name use above
```

That will do the trick.